# Q: Why the product of two objects in category $Set$ is the cartesian product?

Tags: category-theory

you can see the definition here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? Do you know what the (categorical) projections are? Where are you stuck proving the universal property?

Comment: Simply because the cartesian product $A\times B=\{(a,b)\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$ of sets/objects $A,B$ equipped with projections $(a,b)\mapsto a$ and $(a,b)\mapsto b$ satisfies the conditions that are mentioned in the definition that you refer to.

Comment: Any set $P$ with the same cardinality as the cartesian product $A \times B$ will do. The key is that there are 'projection' functions $A \leftarrow P \to B$ satisfying the universal property. These functions factor as a bijection $P \to A \times B$ followed by the usual projection functions $A \leftarrow A \times B \to B$. Having a canonical choice of product (e.g. cartesian product) is often nicer than having arbitrary choices (e.g. for each pair of sets $A$ and $B$, pick some set whose cardinality is $|A| \cdot |B|$).

Comment: drhab: with notation of wikipedia's article why the morphism $f$ is unique? i start with the definition of product of 2 objects in categories. after i am trying to search what is the product in $Set$ category.it is supposed that i don't know that is the cartesian product. maybe i don't understand what is projection. i read this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(mathematics) . why in diagram is correct the universality??

Comment: drhab: how can i know that your projections are not the $f_1, f_2$ of wiki pedia's article?

Comment: @CliveNewstead Suppose that we don't know $A\times B$ with its canonical projections yet. Is there a way to deduce that the cardinality of any product (in categorical sense) of two sets $A$ and $B$ (in a category of sets) should be $|A|\cdot|B|$? Thanks!

Comment: @bruin: I guess that depends on how you define the product of two cardinal numbers. Usually $|A| \cdot |B|$ is (more-or-less) defined to be the cardinality of $A \times B$, so you would need to have figured out what a cartesian product of $A$ and $B$ is in order to ask the question.

Comment: I have some clue now: for fixed two sets $A,B$, for any set $C$ with two maps $f: C\to A$ and $g:C\to B$, the existence of a common factor $m: C\to P$ (where $P$ is the yet "unknown" product of $A$ and $B$) requires that $|P|\geq |A|\cdot|B|$, because the partition $C/\sim_m$ should be a finer partition of both $C/\sim_f$ and $C/\sim_g$. Given that $|C/\sim_f|\leq|A|$ and $|C/\sim_g|\leq|B|$, it's clear that $|C/\sim_m|\geq |A|\cdot|B|$, which in turn requires that $|P|\geq |A|\cdot|B|$. Btw, I guess the uniqueness of $m$ will make further restriction, so in the end, $|P|=|A|\cdot|B|$.